# Adding existing variable to iFrame URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This may be really basic, but help would be appreciated.

I have the following script that can be added to a custom built web application and embeds within it another page in an iframe.

```
$(function() {
    $('#customframe').after('<iframe src="https://www.myurl.com" style="width:100%;height:200px"></iframe>');
});
```

I need to include a query parameter to the iframe like below

```
$(function() {
    $('#customframe').after('<iframe src="https://www.myurl.com/page.html?id=ThisRecordId" style="width:100%;height:200px"></iframe>');
});
```

`ThisRecordId` variable is already available in the DOM.
If I go to the browser console and just type `ThisRecordId` it displays the value I need for the iFrame.

I am just struggling to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string interpolation for string literals,
use backticks instead of quotes and enclose variable in `${ThisRecordId}` template
More about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Example:

```
let ThisRecordId = 'myidnumber'

$(function() {
    $('#customframe').after(`<iframe src="https://www.myurl.com/page.html?id=${ThisRecordId}" style="width:100%;height:200px"></iframe>`);
});
```